# Snowflakes : Accessing the database objects

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

statement :User/role should have  access to both **database** and **warehouse**  in order to access the tables in snowflakes.

Is this statement correct ?am i understanding it correctly?

Person X has access to database and not having  access to any of the available warehouse.In this case 
 can person x  able to access the tables in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases are storage for Snowflake.  Warehouse is compute.  So, in order to query data in Snowflake, you need access to (a) a database, schema, and table, as well as (b) a warehouse in order to execute a query against that data.

To answer your question, Person X has no compute to get to the data in the database, so, no.